# How can I pass a time string in the uri path to a Google Cloud Endpoints API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to pass a time value as a string in the path to a Google endpoints API.

If I use "15:00" as the value, I get the error:

```
"No endpoint found for path: conference/v1/dislikedSessions/Keynote/15:00"
```

The path is found if I send a string like "void" or a number like "1500".

Resource Container

```
SESS_TYPETIME_REQUEST = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    typeOfSession=messages.StringField(1),
    startTime=messages.StringField(2),
)
```

Endpoint code:

```
    @endpoints.method(SESS_TYPETIME_REQUEST, SessionForms,
        path='dislikedSessions/{typeOfSession}/{startTime}',
        http_method='GET', name='dislikedSessions')
    def dislikedSessions(self, request):
      """Return sessions that are not of specified type and earlier than start time."""
      filterTime = datetime.strptime(urllib2.unquote(request.startTime), "%H:%M").time()
```

Yeah, I can use just the numbers (with a change to the strptime method), but I can't understand why the path won't pick up the string like 15:59?

Thanks,
Justin.

Comment: The colon is a [reserved symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) in URLs, so it's best if you percent-encode it.

Comment: Cheers, can do that from the front-end. Doesn't work for the api_explorer locally, though it's fine on the app engine host(!) so all ok.